# Secondary axis not graphing values

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have a list of serial numbers with run times that I am trying to graph via a combo graph in excel then push it to PowerPoint. I am using array operations to get the data for the graph, setting up 3 `seriescollections` and trying to get the serial numbers in a bar chart with counts, then line graphs correlating durations (aveage and total) of run times. The data is getting to the graph, and the values are correct in the select data window. Each series is also assigned the correct `axisgroup` (primary or secondary) in the graph's select data window. Any ideas why the plotted points for both lines are "0" (double clicking the data point on the graph also says the value is 0)?

I am dim-ing stuff() as variants. I know it's not right. I should either dim them as an `arr() of type` or `arr as variant`. IDK why it breaks for me when I do it another way, but it does. I'm also ears abouth that. lol. I appreciate any help!!!!

Code Updated with @FaneDuru's help:

```
Option Explicit



Public Sub QuickSortArray(ByRef SortArray As Variant, Optional lngMin As Long = -1, Optional lngMax As Long = -1, _
Optional lngColumn As Long = 0)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim varMid As Variant
    Dim arrRowTemp As Variant
    Dim lngColTemp As Long
    If IsEmpty(SortArray) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If InStr(TypeName(SortArray), "()") < 1 Then  'IsArray() is somewhat broken: Look for brackets in the type name
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If lngMin = -1 Then
        lngMin = LBound(SortArray, 1)
    End If
    If lngMax = -1 Then
        lngMax = UBound(SortArray, 1)
    End If
    If lngMin >= lngMax Then    ' no sorting required
        Exit Sub
    End If
    i = lngMin
    j = lngMax
    varMid = Empty
    varMid = SortArray((lngMin + lngMax) \ 2, lngColumn)
    ' We  send 'Empty' and invalid data items to the end of the list:
    If IsObject(varMid) Then  ' note that we don't check isObject(SortArray(n)) - varMid *might* pick up a valid default member or property
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf IsEmpty(varMid) Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf IsNull(varMid) Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf varMid = "" Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf VarType(varMid) = vbError Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    ElseIf VarType(varMid) > 17 Then
        i = lngMax
        j = lngMin
    End If
    While i <= j
        While SortArray(i, lngColumn) < varMid And i < lngMax
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        While varMid < SortArray(j, lngColumn) And j > lngMin
            j = j - 1
        Wend
        If i <= j Then
            ' Swap the rows
            ReDim arrRowTemp(LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2))
            For lngColTemp = LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2)
                arrRowTemp(lngColTemp) = SortArray(i, lngColTemp)
                SortArray(i, lngColTemp) = SortArray(j, lngColTemp)
                SortArray(j, lngColTemp) = arrRowTemp(lngColTemp)
            Next lngColTemp
            Erase arrRowTemp
            i = i + 1
            j = j - 1
        End If
    Wend
    If (lngMin < j) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, lngMin, j, lngColumn)
    If (i < lngMax) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, i, lngMax, lngColumn)
End Sub

Private Function contArrayFromDscRng(rng As Range) As Variant 'makes 2D array from a discontinuous range i.e. filtered worksheet
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Cells.count, 1 To 1): count = 1
    For Each a In rng.Areas
            For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
                arr(count, 1) = a.Cells(i).Value: count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    contArrayFromDscRng = arr
End Function

Function GetUniqueDict(arr As Variant) As Variant

   Dim dict As Object, i As Long
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = 1
   Next i
   GetUniqueDict = dict.Keys
End Function
```

Comment: When you try `serialNum = rng`, it will not load all the **discontinuous** range in an array, as you (probably) think. It will only load the first range **area**. Then, your `GetUnique` is overcomplicated and does not return correctly. Using a dictionary, you can obtain a unique values array in a function with only 5 code lines...

Comment: ok. I will step through the range and add each element to the array separately.

Comment: how does the ```GetUnique``` return wrong?

Comment: You should iterate between all `rng.Areas` and each cell of each area and place each cell value in the array. I cannot show here the code... I will post an answer showing how to do it and also a simple function returning unique, using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next function to build a continuous array from a discontinuous range:

```
Private Function contArrayFromDscRng(rng As Range) As Variant 'makes 2D array from a discontinuous range
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.cells.count, 1 To 1): count = 1
    For Each a In rng.Areas
            For i = 1 To a.cells.count
                arr(count, 1) = a.cells(i).value: count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    contArrayFromDscRng = arr
End Function
```

You can use it in your code as:

```
serialNum = contArrayFromDscRng(rng)
```

The next function, will extract an array of unique values from another array:

```
Function GetUniqueDict(arr As Variant) As Variant
   Dim dict As Object, i As Long
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = 1
   Next i
   GetUniqueDict = dict.Keys
End Function
```

But it will return a 1D array. It can also be used like data sources for a chart.

But if you like your way of processing a 2D array, you can easily transform the returned 1D array. Inside the function, or outside. Something like this:

```
  Dim arr
  arr = GetUniqueDict(serialNum)
  
  'transform it as a 2D array:
  Dim i As Long
  ReDim serialNum(1 To UBound(arr) + 1, 1 To 1)
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    serialNum(i + 1, 1) = arr(i)
  Next i
```

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. it wasn't much to refactor to get ```serialNum``` to work throughout as a 1D array. That adds quite a bit of efficiency to this code.

Comment: @Chris H. The first function can be easily adapted to also return a 1D array. Mostly, due to the fact that the processed array is extracted from a column range. But it can be adapted to return 1D array from any kind of range... But, in such a case, `GetUniqueDict` must also be adapted to use such an array. Or even to determine what type of array is used and process it accordingly...

Comment: @Chris H. Now, please check your function returning unique against the one I providid. You will see that yours does not return correctly. I didn't try understanding why. It looked useless complicated for such a process...

Comment: now if I could figure out why the second and third series' aren't plotting.

Comment: I would suggest you to place a break point on the code line creating the necessary arrays. Select the line `aveDur(i) = Format(CDate(...` and press `F9`. Then run the code line by line, pressing `F8` and see what's happening with variables against what you want happening. Moving the cursor over the variables, it will display the variable value...

Comment: the data is getting to the graph with the right elements. In the ```select data``` window the values of all the data series' are correct. The point values on the graph are 0 for ```fullseriescollection(2)``` and ```fullseriescollection(3)```. Both series' are set to the 2nd ```axisgroup.``` but with the point values at 0 are not getting plotted.

Comment: in fact, when I comment out everything but either of the line graphs and try t single line graph of just the duration or average duration, neither works. Could there be a problem with excel understanding the time format from the array?